# SMTP JavaMail : Getting SMTPTransport Not Connected error with Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to work with the JavaMail API. I'm trying to send multiple emails using the same transport object to avoid re-authentication.

```
transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect(host, mail.getSenderAddress(), password);
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    transport.sendMessage(mailMessage, mailMessage.getAllRecipients());
}
```

This works fine and I'm able to send 10 e-mails.
Now I want to use threads to send all these e-mails concurrently.
So I created a new class which sends the mail using transport.sendMessage().

```
class MailSender implements Runnable {

    Transport transport;
    MimeMessage mailMessage;

    public MailSender(Transport transport, MimeMessage mailMessage) {
        this.transport = transport;
        this.mailMessage = mailMessage;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            transport.sendMessage(mailMessage,
                    mailMessage.getAllRecipients());
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm creating 10 different threads like :

```
transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect(host, mail.getSenderAddress(), password);
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    new Thread(new MailSender(transport, mailMessage)).start();
}
```

But when I do this, I keep getting the following exception :

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.checkConnected(SMTPTransport.java:2252)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1074)
at com.rubberduck.mymail.MyMailHelper$MailSender.run(MyMailHelper.java:128)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am calling connect just before the for loop, then how come it complains that its not connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on [JavaMail Session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) to get a better idea of what's going on.  Most likely your threading is wrong, or the server is dropping the connection for some reason.

But there's really no point in using threads to send messages on a single connection because all of the work will be single threaded when it gets to the connection.  Only one messages can be sent at a time on the connection.  That's the way SMTP works.  If you want to send multiple messages in parallel, you'll need multiple connections.

Comment: Ohh okay. But when I try to send like a 1000 mails, making new connections everytime, after a while it starts throwing exceptions for too many requests. I'm using Gmail SMTP server. Is there any way in which I can send multiple emails from a single account? I want to do it as fast as possible.

Comment: You don't need to make a connection every time.  You can send a bunch of messages on each connection, and use multiple connections.  If you're using free Gmail, they're going to limit how many messages you can send how frequently.  If you have a paid account, your terms of service should describe what you're allowed to do.

Comment: Yes I tried this and Gmail SMTP doesn't allow more than 10-12 parallel connections. Thanks for your help.